# How to detect if AdWhirl ads failed to load?

Tags: android, adwhirl

How do I detect if an ads fail to load so I can replace the ads view container with something I can show the user. Right now if no ads load my view container just display a black rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

I read class methods of view object of adwhirl and, at the moment, It seems that there are not method to get this information.

But I used the method found at this link:
[Handle AdWhirl onFailure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182632/handle-adwhirl-onfailure)

And It runs properly. It uses custom events feature.

There is only a problem that I can solve: if user has internet connection not available, the app doesn't connect to adwhirl server and you can't launch custom event.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Android version of the SDK come with a class that has optional methods you can implement? For the iPhone version, there're these optional methods in the delegate protocol you can implement that respond to either a sucess or a failure to receive an ad from the AdWhirl server:

```
- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView;
- (void)adWhirlDidFailToReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView usingBackup:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

Maybe something similar exists in the Android SDK?

Comment: If there are I couldn't find it in the Java interface nor the docs. I did find something about custom events but it's still not clear to use that to detect ads failure.