# iOS Adwhirl Touch event detection

Tags: ios, admob, adwhirl, millennial-media

I have implemented Ads on my iOS game application through Adwhirl(as mediation layer), Admob & Millennial Media. I want to check which events are being called when the ads are being clicked  and which events are being called when we close the ads page i.e. after visiting the ad url.

Please help me to detect the touch events. I would appreciate if anybody will provide some more documentation/sample regarding the ads implementation as well.

With Regards,

Vikas

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question in [this SO post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902640/adwhirl-touch-intercept/11597793#11597793